# Retrieving values from a config table for use in a query

Tags: sql, database, oracle, ms-access

I'm thinking about config tables set up like in option 2 [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/163606), where there is one row per configuration option (or "fact") with the name of the fact and the value of the fact.

**What is the appropriate/best way to incorporate this information into another query that has one or more joins?** Note that I'm explicitly not considering procedural SQL or ORM systems; pure SQL only.

For example, consider these tables for a contrived example:

```
tbl_facts (Option_Name, Option_Value)
tbl_employees (Employee_ID, Name, Salary)
tbl_projects (Project_ID, Name, Manager_ID, Revenue)
```

Manager_ID links to tbl_employees to get the employee who manages a project. There is only one manager per project, but an employee may manage multiple projects. For the sake of this example, Option_Value is numeric/double.

Ignoring costs from other employees on the project, etc., let's find out the gross profit of each project as Revenue - [Manager] Salary:

```
SELECT tbl_projects.Project_ID, tbl_projects.Name, 
    (tbl_projects.Revenue - tbl_employees.Salary) AS Gross_Profit
FROM tbl_projects INNER JOIN tbl_employees ON 
    tbl_projects.Manager_ID = tbl_employees.Employee_ID;
```

Easy enough. Now let's say we know that the tax rate on profits is 20%, so we store ("Tax Rate", 0.2) in tbl_facts (among other facts). We want to find out the net profit. The problem is, there isn't a clear way to join this information to what we have so far.

**Options I've seen/considered:**

1. A cartesian/cross join with tbl_facts. However, some flavors of SQL don't support this, or at least don't support it consistently (sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't).

   ```
   SELECT tbl_projects.Project_ID, tbl_projects.Name, 
       (tbl_projects.Revenue - tbl_employees.Salary) AS Gross_Profit,
       tbl_facts.Option_Value * (tbl_projects.Revenue - tbl_employees.Salary) AS Net_Profit
   FROM 
       (tbl_projects INNER JOIN tbl_employees ON 
           tbl_projects.Manager_ID = tbl_employees.Employee_ID),
       tbl_facts
   WHERE tbl_facts.Option_Name="Tax Rate";
   ```
2. Some flavors of SQL support a lookup function (e.g., MS Access's dlookup()). However, this isn't so nice because you have to cast the value to your desired type, and I suspect there is a performance hit.

   ```
   SELECT tbl_projects.Project_ID, tbl_projects.Name, 
       (tbl_projects.Revenue - tbl_employees.Salary) AS Gross_Profit,
       cdbl(dlookup("Option_Value","tbl_facts","Option_Name='Tax Rate'")) *
           (tbl_projects.Revenue - tbl_employees.Salary) AS Net_Profit
   FROM 
       tbl_projects INNER JOIN tbl_employees ON 
           tbl_projects.Manager_ID = tbl_employees.Employee_ID;
   ```
3. Using subqueries to add a contrived "join column". This seems like a terrible option.

   ```
   SELECT tbl_projects.Project_ID, tbl_projects.Name, 
       (tbl_projects.Revenue - sq_employees.Salary) AS Gross_Profit,
       sq_facts.Option_Value * (tbl_projects.Revenue - sq_employees.Salary) AS Net_Profit
   FROM 
       tbl_projects INNER JOIN 
           (SELECT 1 AS Join_Col, tbl_employees.* FROM tbl_employees) AS sq_employees ON 
           tbl_projects.Manager_ID = sq_employees.Employee_ID),
       INNER JOIN
           (SELECT 1 AS Join_Col, Option_Value FROM tbl_facts WHERE Option_Name="Tax Rate") AS sq_facts ON
               sq_employees.Join_Col = sq_facts.Join_Col;
   ```

What is the preferred way of getting this information from such a configuration table? Is it one of the options above, or something else I haven't considered?

Comment: Your tagging is confusing people: are you after an Oracle or a MS Access solution? The two flavours support different syntaxes, so your question is unlikely to have a single coherent solution.

Comment: I'm after the general solution. I'm currently working on a project in MS Access and reference dlookup above, but the problem statement is for RDBMSs in general. I work in Oracle a lot as well, and have encountered this problem there.

Comment: There is no general solution. Different database products will suit different implementations.

Comment: OK, then I'm limiting my scope to Access and Oracle, as tagged. I understand that there may be implementation specific solutions, but I'm interested in how best to use the SQL standard for this kind of situation. I apologize if I'm being naive/idealistic here -- I'm trying to understand the extent to which this very common problem is solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "you have to cast the value to your desired type, and I suspect there is a performance hit"

You have a numeric value stored as a string and you want to do arithmetic with it. So you have to cast it to a number: you might as well make the data conversion explicit as you will be doing it any way.

Oracle does support scalar cursors in the projection. Personally I would do this as a CROSS JOIN on an inline view, as seems to me this is the most expressive way of doing things. Your mileage may vary.

```
SELECT tbl_projects.Project_ID
       , tbl_projects.Name
       , (tbl_projects.Revenue - tbl_employees.Salary) AS Gross_Profit
       , tf.tax_rate * (tbl_projects.Revenue - tbl_employees.Salary) AS Net_Profit
FROM tbl_projects 
  INNER JOIN tbl_employees ON 
    tbl_projects.Manager_ID = tbl_employees.Employee_ID
  CROSS JOIN ( select to_number(Option_Value) as tax_rate
               from tbl_facts
               WHERE Option_Name='Tax Rate') tf
;
```

If you're storing key-value pairs use an Index-Organized Table. It's basically a indexed lookup anyway, so why bother with the table? At least for Oracle. [Find out more.](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CNCPT/indexiot.htm#GUID-DAEC075B-C16D-4A57-898C-70EBCB364F0C)

Answer (score 3):

The usual way is using a simple subquery in the `SELECT` statement:

```
SELECT (SELECT TOP 1 Option_Value As Tax_Rate FROM tbl_facts WHERE Option_Name='Tax Rate'), other_columns
FROM tbl_projects
```

Let's do a quick review of the options:

1. A simple subquery. This can take full advantage of any present indexes, no typecasting, no other problems. It can only return a single column, so it might be less optimized for multiple columns, and will run into an error if multiple rows are returned
2. A Cross join. In contrast to the single subquery, this can return multiple columns. It can also take advantage of any present indexes, and doesn't have typecasting, so there's no reason for it to be less efficient.
3. Lookup functions. These are a bad plan for most occasions, but mainly in Access in UPDATE queries, you need to have an updateable subquery, and a DLookUp can be of use.

So the real answer is: it depends. The simple subquery is the most obvious candidate, the cross join is useful when you need multiple values, and the DLookUp is useful to avoid errors with non-updateable queries.

Of course, when we bring in VBA into the comparison, it gets a little more complex. An alternative using VBA would be to have an Options class, which gets initialized when the database opens, and can cache option lookups.

Comment: I doubt whether that's *"the usual way"*, especially as it uses a syntax which is invalid in Oracle SQL.

Comment: It's the usual way in Access SQL. Since OP was considering using a `DLookUp`, I'm assuming he's using linked tables, and then this is valid SQL, and will work optimally (since it only queries the option table once)

Comment: I might be wrong, but doesn't an inline subquery like you wrote get re-run for every single row? That is, you get n*m row seeks, where n is the number of rows in tbl_projects, and m is the number of rows in tbl_facts. Wouldn't it be better to have that subquery in the FROM clause, e.g., as a crossjoin like @APC mentions?

Also, APC, can't you rewrite his code to be valid Oracle SQL as follows:
    SELECT (SELECT Option_Value AS Tax_Rate FROM tbl_facts WHERE Option_Name='Tax Rate' WHERE rownum <=1), other_cols from tbl_projects.

Comment: An inline subquery will only get rerun if you're referring to a column from the outer query. In this case, it will only run once.

Comment: I would hope OPTION_NAME is a unique key, otherwise the TOP sub query as written here returns an essentially random value, which doesn't seem to me desirable in a financial calculation. If it is a unique key the Oracle optimizer is clever enough to run the subquery once. I can't speak to the MS-Access optimizer.

Comment: Yup, that's an assumption. The cross join would return N rows for every row if it wasn't an unique key. The Access optimizer is smart enough to execute it only once.

Answer (score 2):

**Fix the data model before you start writing queries.**  Split `OPTION_VALUE` into multiple columns, like `OPTION_NUMBER`, `OPTION_STRING`, and `OPTION_DATE`.

Never store data in the wrong type.  This is a disaster waiting to happen.  A single column named `OPTION_VALUE` may seem like a simple solution but you will pay for this later, either with intermittent bugs or complex queries.

This was recommended in [the top answer in the question you referenced](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/163607/3393).  I've also written about this in [this post](https://method5.github.io/Improve-Entity-Attribute-Value-models-with-proper-data-types/).

To summarize, using multiple columns in an EAV model:

1. Improves performance - Oracle can understand the data better and make better plans
2. Reduces storage - specific data types are better optimized to store data
3. Simplifies validation - validating numbers and dates is not as trivial as you might think
4. Improves type safety - Oracle does not have to run SQL statements in the order written.  This SQL statement is dangerous and will intermittently fail:

   ```
   select *
   from
   (
       select to_number(option_value) tax_rate
       from tbl_facts
       where option_name='tax rate'
   )
   where tax_rate >= 1
   ```
5. Isn't much more difficult anyway.  In practice, you're always going to know the type of your columns before you do anything with them.